# Or statement in C++

Tags: c++, statements

I'm another newb coding in c++ for the nds using devkit pro and I couldn't find anything online about this, surprisingly. How do I code an or statement like the following:

```
if ((keys & KEY_L && LR==true) or (keys & KEY_X && LR==false))
{
    ...
}
```

If you wanted to say, **"if L key is pressed..."** you would use **"if (keys & KEY_L)..."**

So how would I say **"if LR is true, and the L keys is pressed, or if LR is false, and the X key is pressed"**

Comment: Maybe, I tried to put that and the compiler still says "lvalue required as left hand operator.

Comment: You are confusing `==` for `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LR == true` (mind the **double equal sign**, otherwise you are writing an *assignment* instead of a *comparison*!) is unnecessary: just use `LR`. Similarly, use `!LR` instead of `LR == false`. Also, adding a couple of parentheses won't hurt:

```
if (((keys & KEY_L) && LR) || ((keys & KEY_X) && !LR))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost as you have done, just use `==` for equality comparison:

```
if ((keys & KEY_L && LR==true) || (keys & KEY_X && LR==false))
{
    ...
}
```

While `or` will work, it is merely an alternative token for `||`. Additionally, you can change `LR==false` to just `!LR`.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. For some bizarre reason, the `&&` and `||` operators have higher priority than | and `&`, so you need a few extra parenthesis:

And you need to use == to check for equality.

Change this:

```
if ((keys & KEY_L && LR=true) or (keys & KEY_X && LR=false))
```

to this:

```
if (((keys & KEY_L) && LR==true) or ((keys & KEY_X) && LR==false))
```

Answer (score -1):

1. learn the difference between `&` and `&&`.
2. learn the difference between `==` and `=`.
3. learn how `if` works.  `if(val == true)` is just the same as `if(val)`...
4. use parenthetical groupings to make smaller boolean expressions and build them up.

Comment: Downvoted because this is NOT an answer - should be a comment. Could easily be edited to a valid answer though.

Comment: @JBentley "use parenthetical groupings to make smaller boolean expressions and build them up." -- answer.  1-3 are recommended as prereq exercises.

Comment: @JBentley that is incorrect, his use of `or` is fine - `or` is allowed in C++ and is the same as `||`.  As such the only problems I could see were his use of `&`, `=` and building up a larger statement.